# What is the meaning of "dignant"?

Tags: meaning

The novelist Kingsley Amis - *Lucky Jim* (1954) uses the word though he puts it in quotation marks. It appears three times in the novel.

First use:

> "Well, if you drink as much as that you must expect to feel a bit
>   off-colour the next day, mustn't you?" She drew herself upright in her
>   seat in a schoolmarm attitude.
>         He remembered his father, who until the war had always worn stiff white collars, being reproved by the objurgatory jeweller as
>   excessively *"dignant"* in demeanour. This etymological sport
>   expressed for Dixon exactly what he objected to in Christine. He said
>   rather coldly: "Yes, I must mustn't I?"

Second use:

> How well really the Callaghan girl had behaved, in spite of her
>   stand-offishness at times, and how sound her suggestion had been.
>   That, and her laughing fit, proved that she wasn't as **"dignant"** as
>   she looked. He remembered uneasily the awful glow of her skin, the
>   distressing clarity of her eyes, the immoderate whiteness of those
>   slightly irregular teeth.

Third use:

> "Not that I think there's anything foolish in coming to see you. Oh, I
>   just don't seem to be able to put it in any way that sounds at all
>   sensible." Little by little and intermittently, she was adopting her
>   "dignant" tone and physical attitude.

**There is no OED entry for *dignant***

Comment: Probably intended to be an antonym for ***indignant***.

Comment: Seems like a back-formation from *indignant* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation), but it's not being used as a simple antonym of *indignant*. Seems like it's being used to mean *dignified*.

Comment: Reading the passage again, it's rather confusing. It seems like the girl behaved well and gave a nice suggestion, which suggests to the narrator that she was not as "dignant" as she appeared (where a dignant appearance is characterized by an *awful* glow, *distressing* eyes, *immoderate* and *irregular* teeth). So "dignant" seems to be being used negatively.

Comment: @Silenus It appears three times, in all, in the novel. I have edited my question to include all three contexts. But I have to admit, like you, to being a bit confused. I am thinking that it means *dignified*, stripped of its dignity (so to speak).

Comment: See 'gruntled', 'fatuous', and 'vidious'.

Comment: French *digne* and *digné*: dignified. *indigne*: undignified. But *indigné*: indignant

Comment: I would think the ‘dignity’ link is a bit of a red herring here: to me, it reads as just an antonym to _indignant_. If _indignant_ means ‘readily showing [negative] emotion, wont to flare up’, then _dignant_ would presumably mean something along the lines of ‘stiff upper lip’: emotionless, stiff, aloof. Stiff, white colours are definitely dignant; laughing fits and skin glow definitely aren’t. In the third use, I’m assuming she’s moving from quite emotional speech back into a reserved manner. Does that fit?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think you've probably hit the nail on the head, if you would care to post it as an answer. As I've edited to say, the OED has no entry on "dignant". I can only assume it is of Kingsley Amis' own coinage. But I think your suggestion is probably the meaning he was giving it.

Answer (score 5):

I assume **Dignant** is made up of **dignity + ant**, hence it is a person who possesses dignity.

According to the urban dictionary:

**Dignant**:
To have and display dignity.

Acknowledgement of another individual within or about to enter ones own personal space.

"The newspaper boy was dignant enough to say hi to me this morning on my way to the store."

[Source link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dignant)

Comment: How exactly does it differ in meaning from *dignified*?

Comment: I believe it to be an important element to Amis's plot in *Lucky Jim*. I am only just one-third of the way into the book. So when I have finished it I will report back.

Comment: I re-read the three passages and here the meaning of dignant seems slightly stiff collared and has the implications of holier of thou and stiffness. In fact the second passage makes it very clear, "in spite of her stand-offishness at times, ..... her laughing fit, proved that she wasn't as "dignant" as she looked."